# Handling detection limits in a Series

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas TimeSeries with values of `<0.1` that indicate detection limits:

```
In [1]: type(ts)
Out[1]: pandas.core.series.TimeSeries

In [2]: ts[55:63]
Out[2]: Date
2006-08-07    0.8809099
2006-08-21     1.027876
2007-07-10    0.5982836
2007-07-26          0.8
2007-08-09         <0.1
2007-08-23     1.013378
2008-07-14    0.6568888
2008-07-29    0.6966623
Name: PO4 uM
```

I've been trying:

```
ts.str.contains('<0.1')
```

but can't figure out how to use this to replace my data values.

How best to replace these detection limit indicators with values that Pandas can handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're best bet is to remove these special values **when reading in** (that way your `dtype` will be correct, `float64`).
To do this [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) (and most similar functions) have an `na_values` argument:

> `na_values` : list-like or dict, default None
>       Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values

*Note: I've copied `ts[55:63]` and used `read_clipboard` (which also takes this argument).*

```
In [1]: pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+', header=None, na_values='<0.1')
Out[1]: 
            0         1
0  2006-08-07  0.880910
1  2006-08-21  1.027876
2  2007-07-10  0.598284
3  2007-07-26  0.800000
4  2007-08-09       NaN
5  2007-08-23  1.013378
6  2008-07-14  0.656889
7  2008-07-29  0.696662
```

Into a (Time)Series you could use:

```
ts = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+', header=None, na_values='<0.1',
                       index_col=['date'], squeeze=True, names=['date', 'P04'],
                       parse_dates=['date'])

In [3]: ts
Out[3]: 
date
2006-08-07    0.880910
2006-08-21    1.027876
2007-07-10    0.598284
2007-07-26    0.800000
2007-08-09         NaN
2007-08-23    1.013378
2008-07-14    0.656889
2008-07-29    0.696662
Name: P04
```

*This seems a much cleaner way than using:*

```
ts[ts.str.contains('<0.1')] = np.nan
```

Comment: Yes, using na_values with pd.ExcelFile.parse worked to replace the <0.1 values with NaN, but I don't really want NaN here, because below detection limit is very different than missing values (Tufte argued that leaving out "no damage" values on the plot of o-ring damage played a significant role in the Challenger disaster). I would like to replace the `'<0.1'` values with `0.1` to be conservative. Unfortunately the Series with the `'<0.1'` values also had NaNs, so I had to do this to get it to work:`ts[ts.str.contains('<0.1').replace(NaN,False)]=0.1`

Comment: @RichSignell You could use `converters` argument e.g. `pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+', header=None, converters={1: lambda x: 0.1 if x=='<0.1' else x})` :)

Comment: Andy, I would love to use the converters approach, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm sure it's something simple. `urllib.urlretrieve(url='http://epi.whoi.edu/ipython/results/mdistefano/Falmouth_data.csv',filename='Falmouth_data.csv');pd.read_csv('Falmouth_data.csv',index_col='Date',
    na_values=['?',None,'NS','no sample left','Sample Destroyed','machine error','#VALUE!'],
    converters={'PO4 uM': lambda x: 0.1 if x=='<0.1' else x})`

Comment: @RichSignell I get a 404 on that url, so I'm afraid I can't help. Also, I think this would be better for you to ask as a separate question rather than here :)